# Discuss whether the following sequence is Cauchy or not

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $p>1$. Set
\begin{align}
x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k p^k,
\end{align}
where $ \forall k:|\alpha_k| < p$. I wonder: Is this sequence Cauchy?. My guess is no because the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha_k p^k$ diverges since $\alpha_k p^k \not\to 0$. But I do not want this solution (if it is true). I want a solution based only on the convergence of sequences and Cauchy criterion.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer has to depend on the choice of $\alpha_k$. If all $\alpha_k=1$ then the sum diverges. If all $\alpha_k = 0$ it converges.

Comment: Well take $\alpha_k = 1/k! > 0$. Then $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \alpha_k p^k$ converges to $e^p - 1$.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake @paulblartmathcop

Comment: No problem at all!